Не понимаю почему видео на сайте воспроизводится со звуком, только с 3й попытки
Я в этом очень плохо разбираюсь, код нашёл в интернете. Я не автор этого кода.
Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу просто кликнуть один раз на видео, чтобы оно начало работать.
Т.е. 1е видео из 6ти автозапускается, потом я на него нажимаю, видео оставливается, потом я опять нажимаю и оно воспроизводится без звука, потом мне ещё раз надо на него нажать, чтобы пошёл звук. Но видео уже при этом уже почти закончилось.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Что бы оно автовоспроизводилось без звука, но при нажатии значка "play" видео начало воспроизводиться с самого начала со звуком, с первого раза. Спасибо.
Пример работы этого кода: https://arenda-beautycab.moscow/am


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
let playList = {
  '1' : 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/111/1.mp4?dl=1',
  '2' : 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/111/6.mp4?dl=1',
  '3' : 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/111/7.mp4?dl=0',
  '4' : 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/111/2.mp4?dl=0',
  '5' : 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/111/3.mp4?dl=0',
  '6' : 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/111/4.mp4?dl=0'
};
for (var key in playList) {
    $('.t994__item-wrapper:eq('+(+key-1)+') .t994__content').before('<div class="t994__video-wrapper"><video class="t994__video" style="object-fit: cover;background-size: cover;  width: 100%; height: 100%;"  playsinline="" preload="auto" muted="muted"><source src="'+playList[key]+'"></video><div class="t994__video-btn"></div><div class="t994__video-btn-mute"></div></div>');
};
let videoNum = $('.t994__video').length;
function pauseVideo(){
    $('.t994__video').each(function( index ) {
        let thisVideo = $(this);
        if (  $(this).get(0).played ) $(this)[0].pause(); 
        thisVideo.siblings('.t994__video-btn-mute').removeClass('mute_show');
    });
    $('.t994__video-btn').removeClass('playbtn_hide');
    setTimeout(function(){
        let findVideo = $('.t994__item.t-slds__item_active').find('video');
        if ( findVideo.length ){
            findVideo.next('.t994__video-btn').addClass('playbtn_hide');
            findVideo[0].play();
            findVideo.siblings('.t994__video-btn-mute').addClass('mute_show'); 
        };
    }, 100);    
};
$('.t994__item-wrapper').on('click' , '.t994__video-btn-mute' ,function(e){ 
    $('.t994__video').prop('muted', false); 
    $('.t994__video-btn-mute').addClass('mute_dis');
});
$('.t994__content, .t994__video-btn').click(function(){
    let videoLn = $(this).closest('.t994__item-wrapper').find('video');
    if( videoLn.length ){
        if (  videoLn.get(0).paused ) {
            videoLn.next('.t994__video-btn').addClass('playbtn_hide');
            videoLn.get(0).play();
            videoLn.siblings('.t994__video-btn-mute').addClass('mute_show');
        } else {
            videoLn.next('.t994__video-btn').removeClass('playbtn_hide');
            videoLn.get(0).pause();
            videoLn.siblings('.t994__video-btn-mute').removeClass('mute_show'); 
        }
    };
});
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.t994__item:first video')[0].play();
}, 1000);

let slideline = document.querySelector('.t994__slidecontainer');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        var newVal = $(mutation.slideline).prop(mutation.attributeName);
        if (mutation.attributeName === "data-slide-pos") { pauseVideo()};  
});
});
observer.observe( slideline , {  attributes: true});
});
</script>

<style>
.t994__video-wrapper { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
}


.t-slds__wrapper {
        border-radius: 10px !important
}


.t994__video-btn , .t994__video-btn-mute {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6465-3064-4962-b733-383664376338/Group_8.svg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.t994__video-btn-mute{
    display:none;
    background-image: url(https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3938-6263-4461-b031-363134353565/volume_1.svg);
}
.playbtn_hide{opacity:0}
.t994__video-btn:hover {transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1.1)}
.mute_show{display:block}
.mute_dis{display:none !important}

</style>



